# Which one is faster, USA based AWS Servers vs local servers in Malaysia?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, vps, ubuntu-18.04, latency

I have been tasked to create a local university database for a Malaysian Client.

The client is requesting us to use Amazon Web Services as they bought into the marketing hype. I told them that AWS' closest servers are in Singapore, and it is probably better to use local Malaysian servers to ensure speed.

They are saying that a lot of malaysian companies use AWS and they seem to have no problem with speed. One example is [https://www.iproperty.com.my](https://www.iproperty.com.my/) which is the largest real estate website in Malaysia and they have their servers located in the USA.

I'm a little confused here..... seems like being "local" has no speed benefit.... to such that it maybe a myth to say that 'local servers are faster'...

What do you guys think?

Comment: The ping between Singapore and Malaysia is about 10ms according to Google. That's incredibly fast compared with what we get in NZ, which is about 35ms to AWS Sydney or 180ms to the USA. You won't have any performance problems with a 10ms ping. Suggest though if you don't know much about networking or AWS maybe you need an AWS specialist to help you out with this - AWS is a complex enterprise environment.

Comment: Note  many companies use CDN’s that will make the website *appear to be close to user* (or testing tool) and this fast and responsive  while the actual servers are elsewhere for

Comment: Thanks Herman, though yn the case of IProperty.com.my, they're using Cloud Front (CDN) servers in USA!

Comment: CloudFront is global and uses endpoints all over the planet, based on the location of the user requesting the web site. It is fast because Malaysian users hit the Cloudfront edge location in KL.